# Azure Logic App HTTP Listen Not updating values

Tags: json, azure, http, azure-logic-apps

The values never update, when i send the http requests from postman. I am using fake your json-schema to go from the schema and create the object but i cannot get the logic app trigger to accept the values. The logic app http listener is working and i get a good request but it doesnt listen :(

```
{
"properties": {
"Email": {
  "type": "string",
  "value": ""
},
"EmployeeId": {
  "type": "string",
  "value": ""
},
"FirstName": {
  "type": "string",
  "value": ""
},
"JobCode": {
  "type": "string",
  "value": ""
},
"LastName": {
  "type": "string",
  "value": ""
},
"Ledger": {
  "type": "string",
  "value": ""
},
"NTID": {
  "type": "string",
  "value": ""
},
"Title": {
  "type": "string",
  "value": ""
}
},
"required": [
"Email",
"EmployeeId",
"FirstName",
"LastName",
"Ledger",
"NTID",
"Title"
],
"type": "object"
}
```

is the schema and below is the object i am sending`{
  "Email": "in",
  "EmployeeId": "exercitation qui nulla anim Duis",
  "FirstName": "reprehenderit magna",
  "LastName": "dolore",
  "Ledger": "dolore occaecat deserunt",
  "NTID": "id nisi exercitation ut",
  "Title": "laboris veniam in voluptate",
  "JobCode": "laboris voluptate mollit"
}`

all the values on the http input are ""

Comment: Couple of things you can check. Are you using a POST-VERB? Did you set the "Content-Type"-header to "application/json" on your request?

Comment: That was it i forgot the content-type...derp. Post as answer so i can mark it :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the "Content-Type"-header to "application/json" on your request?